# How do I find the geographic location of an IP address in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

How do I determine what country an IP address is located in?

Comment: @Szu How has that question got anything to do with getting the IP Address?

Comment: The OP needs to know which network interface they want the address of, before using that code.

Comment: Download English IP2Location CSV database from here http://www.ip2location.com/free/country-multilingual and parse the CSV with your IP.

Comment: why don't you use the the geolocation service to fetch the geographical name of the street, the city or the country?

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for comment!

I'm find answer from topic [How to get user external IP and Geolocation Programmatically in iOS](http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-get-user-external-ip-and-geolocation-data-in-ios/) and edit code to result:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *requestHTTP = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ip-api.com/json"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

[requestHTTP setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[requestHTTP setValue: @"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requestHTTP];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"IP response: %@ ",responseObject);
    NSString *myIP = [responseObject valueForKey:@"query"];
    NSLog(@"IP: %@", myIP);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];
[op start];
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to pay attention to their policy since you are using ip-api.com. http://ip-api.com/docs/